# Is it acceptable to downvote an answer with one upvote so I can flag it VLQ?

Tags: discussion, flags

I just encountered along the lines of

> I'm not familiar with X, but this should help "insert link to 3rd party site"

I wanted to flag it VLQ but I couldn't because it has one upvote.

I thought *time to trick the system* and I

1. Downvoted
2. Flagged VLQ
3. Removed downvote

Shortly after I asked myself if I had handled that right. Searched SE and google for a while but couldn't find anything related, hence my question.

I don't want to discuss the quality of the answer and if flagging it was the right choice, but if the way I handled it is acceptable.

I know that flags cannot be retracted, but this will be good for me to know in future situations.

Comment: Why remove your downvote? If you thought it was bad enough to VLQ why wasn't it bad enough to leave the downvote?

Comment: @bluefeet I often think about that. I think this answer can be useful, because it links to an informative page where OP might find an answer to his problem, but on the other hand I think it is low quality, *because* it links away from SO. I don't always both flag **and** vote. I see alot of different opinions here on meta SO that talk about different ways to handle situations, and it's not 100% clear to me what the perfect action is. So I didn't leave the downvote because I don't agree that it is "not useful"

Comment: VLQ means that it should be deleted immediately because it's unsalvageable. If you think it's bad enough to be deleted, then I just don't get why it's not bad enough for a downvote. If you're unsure, then maybe you should just move along to something else.  If it _might_ be useful, then **edit it** to make it better.

Comment: Of course this is valid.  Such a poor answer getting upvoted is very suspicious anyway.  Typical scenario is a question-blocked user creating a new account, posting bogus answers with that new account and using is old account to vote them up.  Back in business in ten minutes.

Comment: @bluefeet *If you think it's bad enough to be deleted, then I just don't get why it's not bad enough for a downvote.* I understand where you're coming from and I admit that makes sense. I just try to follow the "rules" and only downvote if the reason on the tooltip applies. Often that is the case, but in this case, I felt it was not, that's why I did flag but not downvote. Also I do sometimes edit such answers to make them better, but I know little about the topic of the question so I figured it was better to leave it.

Comment: *Tricking the system : pretend to do what you should have done. What..*

Comment: @Holmes I don't follow

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A VLQ flag means that the post should be deleted right away, in other words, there is no way to fix it or salvage it into anything useful for anyone.

If you downvote an answer specifically to flag it VLQ, but remove your downvote, then you need to ask yourself...was it really low quality?  My feeling would be probably not.  If it were bad enough to flag it as VLQ, then leave the downvote along with your flag. If your worried about losing the -1 rep, then you'll get it back if/when the answer is deleted. The downvote is also the indicator to the rest of the community, even the user posting the answer, that something is wrong with the answer and maybe it needs to be removed/improved or something.

Think about it this way, if you truly believe the answer is "useful" and doesn't need to be downvoted, then why are you flagging as VLQ asking for it to be removed?  Seems like a strange way to handle the situation.   If it's useful enough to not downvote it, then try to edit it into something better.

Comment: I was only thinking of OPs perspective, instead of all future visitors as well. In the second case, I would not call that answer useful for the same reason I find it VLQ. I see now that down voting would be the right thing to do. Thanks for clearing things up

Comment: If VLQ is recommending for immediate deletion why doesn't it say that?  I've been operating under the impression that it went to review or something similar.  Description:  This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: @rogerdeuce If something is _unlikely to be salvageable through editing_, why would we keep it around?  The flag description also says _might need to be removed_ which equals deletion.

Comment: but it says unlikely and might, vs. can't and will, which implies (at least in my mind) that someone else is going to look at it and try to fix it if they can.  In the answer that prompted this question it seems like moving the relevant information from the link, to the answer itself would indeed salvage the answer.

Comment: @rogerdeuce If you think it could be salvaged by an edit, then you should edit it. Flagging VLQ is basically asking for it to be deleted.

Comment: @rogerdeuce It does go to a review. Once there, if enough people agree then it does get deleted. If people don't, or the flag ages away, it doesn't. That is the reason for the specific language on the flag. It *might* be deleted if people that review it thinks it should be.

Comment: @MatthewGreen VLQ flags don't age away - they linger until someone processes them, either a review queue or a moderator.

Comment: @bluefeet Oh right, I knew that. I think...