# Why are code-only answers in the low quality review queue, if they should not be deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

After asking the question *[Can we have a code only reason for deletion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312678/can-we-have-a-code-only-reason-for-deletion)*, it seems to be clear that code-only answers should not be deleted.

**Why** are code-only answers in the low quality review queue, if they should not be deleted?

---

There are a lot of similar questions, but they are not asking the same thing.

For example, *[What to do with code-only answers in Low Quality Posts queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300694/what-to-do-with-code-only-answers-in-low-quality-posts-queue)*.

Comment: Because people flag them ;) Not everybody knows when to and when not to flag a post

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes, but someone must be approving the flags? ah ha! didn't expect that one did you? ;)

Comment: When an answer is flagged as VLQ the answer goes into the LQ queue, the flag is not reviewed before it enters the queue (that is what the queue itself is for)

Comment: @TimCastelijns I thought flags were approved or declined? no??

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Also NAA flags.

Comment: My tagline should be *I honestly have no idea how this system works at all*

Comment: *"I thought flags were approved or declined"*  - That's what that queue does. If people decide not to delete the post, the flag is declined.

Comment: Basic logic: code only answers should not be deleted just for being code only. But they can be deleted for being low quality. Just like any other type of answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally, they get into the LQP queue because someone is silly enough to flag them as VLQ or NAA. Sometimes the automated heuristics shove them in, presumably because they're very short or something.

In any case, there are a few ways they can then leave the queue:

- Recommend Deletion/Delete consensus. This is almost always wrong for code-only answers.
- Looks OK consensus. This is often the right choice. If unanimous or nearly so, declines the flag(s); otherwise, just disputes.
- Edit (from queue, or outside of queue in case of VLQ flag specifically I believe). This is occasionally the right thing to do if the explanation isn't difficult to add, or is already basically present. Always disputes the flag(s).
- ♦ mod action. Visibility in the mod queue is delayed by something like half an hour to allow a chance at community response.

As you can see, a flag can be handled either by a ♦ mod or by one or more 2k+ users. Unfortunately, the semantics are a bit different between these two handling queues, leading to confusion at times, but here the relevant point is twofold:

- *Someone* has to check those flags to see if there is the slightest bit of merit, and often that someone is you.
- Sometimes these flags will be declined by a ♦ instead of by the 2kers.

Comment: `Sometimes the automated heuristics shove them in, presumably because they're very short or something.` > http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276626/1402846

Comment: If they are to be edited, shouldn't they rather go into that other queue for questions to be edited?

Comment: @Trilarion: At present, H&I is for *questions*, not answers. Also, editing usually isn't the right resolution. In any case, the software doesn't have any particular way to tell whether an answer qualifies for edit-would-fix-but-probably-doesn't-need-deletion-anyway — that's what the LQP queue is for. (Some superficially similar answers *do* need to be deleted, especially on other sites.)

Comment: I usually decline flags for very low quality of code only answers. I guess they are valid answers, although sometimes the lack of explanation can make them less useful which would be a reason for downvoting. In the queue they are just a waste of effort. Probably there is some statistics available somewhere how likely it is for a code only answer to be deleted in this queue.

Answer (score 10):

> Why are code only answers in the low quality review queue, if they should not be deleted?

Because people flag them ;) Not everybody knows when to and when not to flag a post.

> Someone must be approving the flags?

When an answer is flagged as VLQ the answer goes into the LQ queue, the flag is not reviewed before it enters the queue (that is what the queue itself is for).

Some additional info: [flagging a post as VLQ is saying "this post is crap, "cannot be salvaged and it should be deleted right away".](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306133/1843331)

Comment: We need this verified

Comment: I think this is bunk Tim..  all flags are reviewed or auto botted.. in some cases

Comment: Who do you think does the review of said flags? It is us, in the LQ queue. If all flags had to be reviewed before entering the queue, mods would have busy times

Comment: I've had flags declined by mods.. *why, why, why* I ask you? :D

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286972 from shog

Comment: I *sniff* apologise for saying **bunk** Tim, can you forgive me *sniff*

Comment: It may be good if the flags would be reviewed, even if only to reduce the work load. One could learn from the results, if certain types are highly probable to be declined like code only section, just don't accept them.

Answer (score 1):

Code-only answers is not a reason for deletion, but still a reason for improvement. They are in low quality queue because it is strongly suggested that they're should be improved with additional explanation.

Comment: *They are in low quality queue because it is strongly suggested that they're should be improved* flagging a post as low quality is saying "this post is crap, "cannot be improved and it should be deleted right away"

Comment: I think you're answering to the wrong question, I posted two in succession

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I'll cite what is written under "Low Quality Posts" queue: "Identify, then ***improve*** or delete low-quality posts". Not what you wrote.

Comment: @MsYvette, no, I'm answering your exact question: "why are they in this LQ queue" - because this queue is for improvement too, not only for deletion".

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306133/1843331, that once helped clear things up for me

Comment: @TimCastelijns, question is about queue, not the flag.

Comment: The low-quality reviewers are likely not able to improve the post much though. It is more helpful to leave a comment for the poster than flagging it as low quality.

Comment: Maybe they should get into the "Help and Improvement" queue instead.