# Can we reduce the amount of code-only answers entering the Low Quality Post review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, code-only-answers

Whenever I go into the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, I'd say a good 75% or more of them are code-only answers. I almost always say they "Look OK".

Looking through some older meta posts, this has been brought up [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312683/why-are-code-only-answers-in-the-low-quality-review-queue-if-they-should-not-be) and [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers) and [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262695/new-answer-deletion-option-code-only-answer), and the general consensus seems to be that code-only answers are fine, yet people are continuously using this flag.

The flag description reads:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Which sounds appropriate to me, as there are often a lot of truly low quality posts riddled with misspellings, incoherent grammar, broken code snippets, etc. that need to be fixed up/edited. I'd like to spend more time fixing those than approving code only answers.

Has any action been taken to reduce the amount of code-only answers entering the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, and if so, is it working? Can we get any stats on how effective it's been?

Comment: sounds like a great case for some JIT education

Comment: I assumed most of that was [automatic flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/5764553) (the [Meta.SE link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) makes it seem less likely since code-only is not listed). If that's actually from users flagging, that's disturbing. Almost as disturbing as all the incorrect reviews I've discovered since gaining access to the queue.

Comment: The flag isn't the only way that answers enter the LQRQ. We all know that code without an explanation isn't a good answer, and the help center makes clear that.

Comment: I just had to check this out since all of the VLQ flags I raise on questions about code that contain no actual code get declined.

Comment: @Braiam Can you point out one excerpt from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer where they say a code only answer isn't a good answer?

Comment: @dwirony that specific page isn't all too specific about it, you can deduce it from the fact that *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*. Sometimes code is all the explanation you need, but often times it isn't. Still, the page definitely could spell it out a little more.

Comment: @Gimby Sure, I can deduce that - but when I re-read the flag description, I just don't see how a code only answer (while maybe not being GREAT) has "severe formatting or content problem".

Comment: @dwirony forget about the text in the flag. Look at the guidance by the review queue.

Comment: @Braiam "Forget the text in the flag": So the text doesn't adequately describe the flag's intention, right? I agree that a lot of code-only answers are _low-quality_ in that they are *not very helpful* – especially if you are new to a topic – without accompanying guidance or explanations. In addition to this, I assume some low-quality flags are _plagliarism flags in disguise_, i.e. a bare code-snippet was stolen from an existing answer. I think I personally had the thought to flag them that way, before starting to properly use custom moderator flags with "Plagiarism: Copied from SO.com/a/123".

Comment: @Braiam Again, can you give me a *specific excerpt* from the guidance in the review queue which speaks against code-only answers??

Comment: Yes, I agree on this. While code + comments is often better I would say 1. code only is often more than adequate, **especially** *commented code* (!) and 2. code-only answers probably average in the top 10% of quality answers, as opposed to comment-only which is usually awful. Plenty of exceptions to these trends, of course. In my case I know to avoid it except when it's just super self-explanatory and OP agrees. However, it is tempting to do your commenting as commented code so that you can type it all in your IDE. I do this sometimes, though I usually remember to uncomment it on SO

Comment: "So the text doesn't adequately describe the flag's intention, right?" The text doesn't describe what it is expected of you to do in the queue. The flag is used for one thing, the queue is used for many things.

Comment: @Braiam It's the "Low Quality Post" review queue because the posts have been tagged with the "Low Quality" tag. How is it used for anything *but* reviewing low quality flagged posts?

Comment: No, they are not tagged. Tags, in the context of SE, means a very specific thing: tags of the questions. The purpose of the low quality post queue is to "[i]dentify, then improve or delete low-quality posts". Note how it isn't only for deletion.

Comment: On the contrary, @Hack-R, code-only answers are *rarely* adequate, at least for questions that are good in the first place.  I will make a special exception for answers that embed the wanted prose into the code in the form of comments, however, as that's "code-only" only on a technicality.  Those are not the answers I think we're actually talking about here.

Comment: @dwirony It's not just there to evaluate user-cast low quality flags.  In fact, originally user cast low quality flags didn't even send posts to that queue.  Originally the queue was all about evaluating posts that met an automated system's heuristics for a post that may be bad.  Now it's a combination of both, as user cast low quality flags are mixed in with the automatically generated ones.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Note however that there's a difference between a bad answer, and an answer that is so bad it needs to be deleted.  There's a *big* difference between the two.  Inadequate explanation isn't grounds for deletion of an answer.  It's a great reason to downvote it though.

Comment: Agreed, @Servy.  Correct code that is responsive to the question does not ordinarily constitute an answer bad enough to warrant deletion, so it's fair to ask how to reduce the volume of those that reach the queue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I respectfully completely disagree, usually a code-only answer, especially with comments in the code (commented code), is usually so high quality because people who are posting code typically have the answer the OP needs, at least in my tags. OTOH newer users like to leave comments as answers with no code. I think as long as the code appears self-explanatory to the OP, answerer, and observers it's fine. But like I said, comments make it better.

Comment: I think 75% is a an exaggeration. I would say more like 25%. But anyway, I get your point.

Comment: Your question (especially the summary in the last lines) is whether there are (technical?) mechanisms to reduce code-only answer in VLQ queues and whether statistical information is available on the success. The comment thread here mostly discusses why/whether they should be in the queue and your pariticipation goes along. Would you like to return the topic to the question you have asked?  Then you should stress that in the question even more explicitly. If discussing the whether/why is your actual question, then it is a duplicate.

Comment: ...this must have been changed since I was most active.  Used to be code-only answers were unacceptable because they didn't explain what the problem was.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'd like to avoid the whether/why because I know that has been asked before. I'm truly wanting to know what action has been taken to reduce them entering the queue.

Comment: @Izkata basically, OP is asking where such guidance can be found, because the flag doesn't say that, neither the "how to answer". We can probably found some meta ost with an high upvote answer but that doesn't mean the community have made the official decision that code only answer should be deleted. Also about the thing in comments : what we want is basically that the  code is explaining and what was right in OP's code.

Comment: @Izkata It's always been agreed on that they're usually low quality, and infrequently make for good answers to a question.  There has never been a time where they have merited deletion.

Comment: Hmm, to me it still seems that your actual question is ignored. And I am afraid that will not change if you do not find some clear words in both your question and this comment thread...

Comment: Code-only answers that are commented adequately are, by their definition, **not code-only** and shouldn't be flagged. Anything else, flag away.

Comment: @IanKemp except that a code only answer even without comments is still an attempt to answer, and does not inherently have severe content or formatting problems. As such no flags are warranted on such content. It is entirely possible for a code only answer to be unintelligible or gibberish, in which case it _would_ have severe content problems, but not just because it is code only.