# Code only answers in the LQPQ that are wrong

Tags: discussion, support, low-quality-posts, code-only-answers

So, I came upon a situation I feel is a bit weird, hence I want to ask for clarification. The Low Quality Post queue gave me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417388/3689450) to review. By coincidence, I had already seen it about an hour before it came up for review - I downvoted it and comment to explain why the code suggested was simply wrong. So, what do I do with [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20909824)?

**Looks OK**? I don't agree it with that. I know [code only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312683/why-are-code-only-answers-in-the-low-quality-review-queue-if-they-should-not-be) [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality) [are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers) [accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262695/new-answer-deletion-option-code-only-answer) but I also know this one doesn't work and wouldn't without being completely changed. Should I choose "Looks OK" when I don't think it does?

**Edit**? The most useful edit I can make is to completely re-write the post into a working one. Or alternatively edit it to include an explanation for the code...yet that will explain how it doesn't actually solve OP's problem.

**Recommend Deletion**? Well, none of the reasons match the answer. And none match, because that's not the accepted way to deal with these answers.

**Skip**? I suppose [there is no shame](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) in doing that, but ideologically I find it incorrect, as I haven't skipped it. I already acted upon the answer before it came up for review.

Also, how should I handle this in general - I see some code-only answer that I *know* is wrong/doesn't work for OP. Do I comment and skip? Comment and say it looks OK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not reviewing for "correctness". The fact that the answer is *wrong* is not relevant for the review. **That what votes are for**, and if you have already voted in that answer, kudos to you.

I understand that "it doesn't look good to you", and I feel your pain at having to click *looks ok* when you really believe it doesn't.

But you need to review in the context of the queue you are in.

*Looks ok* means: **it doesn't need to be deleted**. I agree that this button could be reworded to be *less positive*. I do not think you are the only one that dislikes its current wording.

Comment: that is helpful thanks. By the way, are there written guidelines for that? I tried looking but the best I could find is some blog posts about reviewing in general, meta questions on how to handle code-only answers and such. I didn't find an actual explanation of when "Looks OK" is merited and as consequence, I'm most likely under-utilising it in favour of "Skip" when I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, the label might be too long for a button but could be the caption. For reference, the current one simply says "this answer doesn't seem low-quality". Also something I disagree with.